# How to replace blank value of a column to [null] in hive to calculate SUM

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql

could you please guide.

I have following input table.

[image]

I tried below query.

```sql
select distinct sum(amount) over partition by date from table1;
```

Here in the table date is type string and amount is of type double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `where` to remove the rows with blank dates, before doing a group by and sum:

```sql
select date, sum(amount)
from table1
where date != ''
group by date
```